# Azure hardware plan scale between single instance in single region and single instance in two regions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-webapps

I have an app in Azure that’s currently a single instance within a single region. It’s running on a Premium v2 P3V2 hardware plan. If I were to spin up a second region so this app was a single instance running in two regions, so two total instances, could I have each region instance run on a Premium v2 P2V2 which is half the cost and half the hardware of the Premium v2 P3V2?

My assumption is yes because currently the single region serves 100% of the traffic demands and by scaling down but also scaling to a second region each would serve about 50% of the traffic demands. Obviously there’s also the added benefit of resiliency by being in a second region.

I’m new to IaaS so looking for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your scenario description, you want understand implications to run your app in two regions with each instance running on a Premium v2 P2V2 plan. This would provide you with the added benefit of resiliency by being in a second region, as you mentioned.

However, it is important to note that running your app in two regions will not necessarily result in each instance serving about 50% of the traffic demands.

The traffic distribution between the two regions will depend on the configuration of your app and the traffic routing rules that you have set up.

Additionally, while running your app on a Premium v2 P2V2 plan may be less expensive than running it on a Premium v2 P3V2 plan, it may also result in lower performance and capacity. So, you must carefully consider the performance and capacity requirements of your app before making any changes to your hardware plan.

Overall, running your app in two regions can provide you with improved resiliency and availability, but it is important to carefully consider the cost and performance implications of any changes to your hardware plan.

As a *side note*, however, before making any changes to your app's infrastructure, it is recommended to perform load testing to ensure that the new configuration can handle the expected traffic demands. You should also consider the impact of the changes on your app's performance, availability, and cost.

**Reference docs:**

[How much does my App Service plan cost?](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans#how-much-does-my-app-service-plan-cost)

[Tutorial: Create a highly available multi-region app in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-region-app) - this reference architecture and decision tree ---
You'll need two instances of a web app that run in different Azure regions for this tutorial.